# .net Core 3.1 error 404 adding background-image in css

Tags: css, asp.net-core, .net-core, background-image

[Imagem Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML75o.png)

I am getting error 404 (in console) when adding background-image: url("/wwwroot/images/bg-01.jpg");

What i did was to remake the login page with a template, and it's all working.
But cant add image to background.

I have a template with pure css and html and js in notepad that is working.only when passing to .net core. the image is with error.
In view i am not using _Layout
The path is correct since i tested touse in a img tag with href:/wwwroot/images/bg-01.jpg and it works fine.
I also tried to use an correct url image from web and same error
Anyone can help.?

Comment: A little bit more context like code snippets will be nice. From where is your css loaded? How is it with the leading "/ "? Are your css things bundled (SCSS)? What is rendered in the page on client side?

Comment: Is my answer helpful?If it is helpful,can you mark it?Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like `url('/images/bg-01.jpg')`,here is a demo:

wwwroot:

[image]

view:

```
<div id="div1">
        <div id="div2">
            Peppa
        </div>
    </div>
 <style>
     #div1 {
         background-image: url('/images/Peppa.jpg');
         width: 279px;
         height: 181px;
     }
     #div2 {
         background-image: url('/images/green.PNG');
         width: 100px;
         height: 50px;
     }
 </style>
```

result：

[image]